# NAT inside destination not initiating

Tags: nat

This lab is done on Dynamips, and the setting is like below:
[image: ip nat inside destination setting]
There are two identical servers(192.168.48.74, 75) inside NAT, and the servers will use one public IP 200.200.17.34/29. R1 is the NAT router, and SW3 is a L3 switch with the servers.

From what I can gather, I can do this with "ip nat inside destination" command.[[2]](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/network-infrastructure-documents/how-to-use-quot-ip-nat-inside-destination-quot-basic/ta-p/3122880) It doesn't let me initiate a session from the server, and I just need outside people being able to access the server.

So, I set up a local address pool RETAIL-WEB-LOCAL which are the server addresses and an access-list RETAIL-WEB-GLOBAL with the public address for the servers. Then I put them together with "ip nat inside destination list RETAIL-WEB-GLOBAL pool RETAIL-WEB-LOCAL" command.

R1 configuration is as follows:

```
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname SeoulR1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 5
!
!
ip cef
no ip domain lookup
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 10.10.11.1 255.255.255.248
!
interface Loopback1
 ip address 192.168.48.2 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.3 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.4 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.5 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.6 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.7 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.8 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.9 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.10 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.11 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.12 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.13 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.14 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.15 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.16 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.17 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.18 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.19 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.20 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.21 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.22 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.23 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.1 255.255.255.224
 ip ospf network point-to-point
!
interface Loopback2
 ip address 192.168.48.34 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.35 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.36 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.37 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.38 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.39 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.33 255.255.255.224
 ip ospf network point-to-point
!
interface Loopback3
 ip address 192.168.64.2 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.64.3 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.64.4 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.64.5 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.64.6 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.64.7 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.64.1 255.255.255.224
 ip ospf network point-to-point
!
interface Loopback4
 ip address 192.168.64.34 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.64.35 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.64.36 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.64.37 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.64.38 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.64.39 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.64.33 255.255.255.224
 ip ospf network point-to-point
!
interface Loopback5
 ip address 192.168.80.98 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.80.99 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.80.97 255.255.255.224
 ip ospf network point-to-point
!
interface Loopback6
 ip address 192.168.80.194 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.80.195 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.80.193 255.255.255.224
 ip ospf network point-to-point
!
interface Serial0/0
 no ip address
 encapsulation frame-relay
 serial restart-delay 0
 no frame-relay inverse-arp
 frame-relay lmi-type ansi
!
interface Serial0/0.13 multipoint
 ip address 200.200.17.5 255.255.255.252
 ip ospf network point-to-point
 frame-relay map ip 200.200.17.6 103 broadcast
!
interface Serial0/1
 ip address 200.200.17.13 255.255.255.252
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial0/2
 no ip address
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial0/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Ethernet1/0
 ip address 200.200.17.18 255.255.255.252
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 full-duplex
!
interface Ethernet1/1
 no ip address
 full-duplex
!
interface Ethernet1/1.15
 encapsulation dot1Q 600
 ip address 166.15.13.1 255.255.255.252
!
interface Ethernet1/1.17
 encapsulation dot1Q 107
 ip address 192.168.32.1 255.255.255.240
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
!
interface Ethernet1/1.18
 encapsulation dot1Q 108
 ip address 192.168.32.17 255.255.255.240
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
!
interface Ethernet1/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 half-duplex
!
interface Ethernet1/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 half-duplex
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 10.10.11.1
 log-adjacency-changes
 area 0 authentication message-digest
 area 192 virtual-link 10.10.13.3 message-digest-key 53 md5 sj79aqj2dn0js
 passive-interface default
 no passive-interface Serial0/0.13
 no passive-interface Serial0/1
 no passive-interface Ethernet1/1.17
 no passive-interface Ethernet1/1.18
 network 192.168.32.1 0.0.0.0 area 1003
 network 192.168.32.17 0.0.0.0 area 1003
 network 192.168.48.0 0.0.0.63 area 1003
 network 192.168.64.0 0.0.0.63 area 1003
 network 192.168.80.96 0.0.0.31 area 1003
 network 192.168.80.192 0.0.0.31 area 1003
 network 200.200.17.5 0.0.0.0 area 192
 network 200.200.17.13 0.0.0.0 area 192
 default-information originate always
!
ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 200.200.17.17
!
!
ip nat pool RETAIL-WEB-LOCAL 192.168.48.74 192.168.48.75 prefix-length 29 type rotary
ip nat inside source list NAT-GRP interface Ethernet1/0 overload
ip nat inside destination list RETAIL-WEB-GLOBAL pool RETAIL-WEB-LOCAL
!
!
ip access-list standard NAT-GRP
 permit 192.168.48.0 0.0.0.63
 permit 192.168.64.0 0.0.16.255
ip access-list standard RETAIL-WEB-GLOBAL
 permit 200.200.17.34
!
control-plane
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 login
!
end
```

SW3 config is as follows:

```
no service password-encryption
!
hostname SW3
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 5
ip cef
!
no ip domain lookup
!
interface Loopback1
 ip address 192.168.48.66 255.255.255.248 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.67 255.255.255.248 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.68 255.255.255.248 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.69 255.255.255.248 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.70 255.255.255.248 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.65 255.255.255.248
 ip ospf network point-to-point
!
interface Loopback2
 ip address 192.168.48.74 255.255.255.248 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.75 255.255.255.248 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.76 255.255.255.248 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.77 255.255.255.248 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.73 255.255.255.248
 ip ospf network point-to-point
!
interface Loopback3
 ip address 192.168.48.82 255.255.255.248 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.83 255.255.255.248 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.84 255.255.255.248 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.85 255.255.255.248 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.81 255.255.255.248
 ip ospf network point-to-point
!
interface Loopback4
 ip address 192.168.80.2 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.80.3 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.80.4 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.80.5 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.80.6 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.80.7 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.80.1 255.255.255.224
 ip ospf network point-to-point
!
interface Loopback5
 ip address 192.168.80.34 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.80.35 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.80.36 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.80.37 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.80.38 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.80.39 255.255.255.224 secondary
 ip address 192.168.80.33 255.255.255.224
 ip ospf network point-to-point
!
interface Loopback6
 description Human Resources - Intranet/Web Service
 ip address 192.168.48.138 255.255.255.248 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.139 255.255.255.248 secondary
 ip address 192.168.48.137 255.255.255.248
 ip ospf network point-to-point
!
interface Port-channel1
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Port-channel2
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface Port-channel3
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 switchport access vlan 210
!
!
interface FastEthernet1/9
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 2 mode on
!
interface FastEthernet1/10
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 2 mode on
!
interface FastEthernet1/11
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 3 mode on
!
interface FastEthernet1/12
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 3 mode on
!
interface FastEthernet1/13
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 1 mode on
!
interface FastEthernet1/14
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-group 1 mode on
!
interface FastEthernet1/15
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
!
interface Vlan108
 ip address 192.168.32.18 255.255.255.240
 ip access-group CTRL-RETAIL-TELLER in
!
interface Vlan708
 ip address 192.168.32.34 255.255.255.240
 ip access-group CTRL-RETAIL-TELLER in
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 10.10.11.3
 log-adjacency-changes
 passive-interface default
 no passive-interface Vlan108
 no passive-interface Vlan708
 network 192.168.32.18 0.0.0.0 area 1003
 network 192.168.32.34 0.0.0.0 area 1003
 network 192.168.48.64 0.0.0.31 area 1003
 network 192.168.80.0 0.0.0.7 area 1003
 network 192.168.80.32 0.0.0.7 area 1003
!
ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip access-list extended CTRL-RETAIL-TELLER
 permit ip 192.168.48.0 0.0.0.15 192.168.48.68 0.0.0.1
 permit ip 192.168.48.32 0.0.0.7 192.168.48.68 0.0.0.1
 deny   ip any 192.168.48.64 0.0.0.7
 permit ip any any
!
control-plane
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 login
!
end
```

ip nat statistics on R1 shows the following:

```
R1#sh ip nat stat
Total active translations: 0 (0 static, 0 dynamic; 0 extended)
Outside interfaces:
  Ethernet1/0
Inside interfaces:
  Ethernet1/1.17, Ethernet1/1.18
Hits: 0  Misses: 0
CEF Translated packets: 0, CEF Punted packets: 0
Expired translations: 0
Dynamic mappings:
-- Inside Source
[Id: 1] access-list NAT-GRP interface Ethernet1/0 refcount 0
-- Inside Destination
[Id: 2] access-list RETAIL-WEB-GLOBAL pool RETAIL-WEB-LOCAL refcount 0
 pool RETAIL-WEB-LOCAL: netmask 255.255.255.248
        start 192.168.48.74 end 192.168.48.75
        type rotary, total addresses 2, allocated 0 (0%), misses 0
Queued Packets: 0
```

Problem: When I tried to ping 200.200.17.34 from ISP, it fails. It doesn't even create any ip nat translation entry. It tries to route the address without going through nat at all. (ISP has a route for 200.200.17.34, and the packet comes to R1 when I debug ip packet. And I added a route for 200.200.17.34 on R1 too because before that route added on, R1 tries to route first and fails. So I thought it's doing the routing first and then translates. But when I added the route, it still doesn't translate.) What have I done wrong?

And I'm not sure if this plays any role, but between R1 and SW3, there's an L2 switch.

Comment: You need to edit your question to give us full network device configurations. You are missing some information.

Comment: @RonMaupin, I did that for R1 & SW3. If you need other info, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You have a static route pointing to another router: `ip route 200.200.17.32 255.255.255.248 Ethernet1/1.17 192.168.32.18`. What is the configuration of that router?

Comment: Man, I made a mistake on that route. It should be {ip route 200.200.17.32 255.255.255.248 Ethernet1/1.18 192.168.32.18}.. let me change that and get back to you. I am sorry.

Comment: OK, but we still need the configuration of the router to which you are routing that traffic. The servers are on the other side of that router.

Comment: That router (connected through e1/1.18 and vlan 108) is SW3 which is working as an L3 switch here.

Comment: That layer-3 switch has no addresses in that network. It doesn't know what to do with traffic destined for that network.

Comment: No, it doesn't. That static route was added because I didn't want R1 to send back the packet to ISP before it tries to translate 200.200.17.34 to 192.168.48.74 or 75. It's not meant to do the routing for 200.200.17.34. (This was added after R1 didn't try to translate 200.200.17.34 but tried to do the routing.)

Comment: Don't add routes that are not meant to route traffic. Any packets with a destination in that network will be dropped.

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't do that normally. This is just to find out if the problem is the order of translating and routing.

Comment: What is the output of show Ip nat trans?

Comment: What is the output of show ip nat trans?  Your destination NAT doesn’t make much sense, traffic from the servers to internet would have its destination changed to the servers private address it if it were destined for 200.200.17.34, why would you need that?  What are you trying to achieve?  If you want the servers to speak to each other using their public addresses, better to use NAT NVI

Comment: @KarlBillington, there's nothing. It doesn't create an entry. I think I have confused you with the static route. Please, ignore the static route. I guess I should change OP. And if I remove the static route, it just pingpongs the packet between ISP and R1.

Comment: If you just want to access the servers from the internet you need to use static pat, delete the destination translation and set up something like: ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.48.74 80 200.200.17.34 80 extendable, then another for the other server, but you can only use port 80 once for the external, so you would have to use another port for the second server

Comment: @KarlBillington, yes, that's why I tried to use 'inside destination' because the client shouldn't be using another port and they should be able to access the servers with an ip address. Or do you think that the IOS I'm using doesn't support ip nat inside destination command?

Comment: Well you can only have a single port 80 on your global, no real way around that, you need two globals if they must use the same port

Comment: @KarlBillington, but I thought it's possible with the destination translation. Because it only let you initiate session from outside, it doesn't really need another port on the inside global to distinguish two different sessions since you can map the session with the outside global and the inside local.

Comment: Just to get things clear, are you trying to access the two internal servers from the internet?  Your goal is for clients on the internet to access your two internal servers?  Are they both web servers?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to let the clients on the internet to access the internal web servers which are identical to each other. So when the clients try to connect to the web server with one outside global address, the router does the load balancing in a round robin fashion and routes the packet to either server.

Comment: OK I don,t think you can do it, the correct statement would be ip nat outside destination list RETAIL-WEB-GLOBAL pool RETAIL-WEB-LOCAL, but you would only translate the global once, to a single private address, you wouldn’t get load balancing

Comment: OK, try the above (change the destination to outside instead of inside), as your pool is type rotary, it should work

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change ip nat inside destination list RETAIL-WEB-GLOBAL pool RETAIL-WEB-LOCAL to: ip nat outside destination list RETAIL-WEB-GLOBAL pool RETAIL-WEB-LOCAL

Comment: Hmm.. I don't get this. I just tried your suggestion, and it didn't support that command. 'ip nat outside' only has source command. And since you implied that to let the session initiated from outside, outside command should be used, I tried to ping 200.200.17.34 from inside with my original setting, it fails. It goes to R1 and it reaches 200.200.17.18 which is nat outside interface on R1. Then it keeps cycling inside that interface. Like :  1 192.168.32.1 268 msec
  2  *  *  *
  3 200.200.17.18 68 msec
  4  *  *  *
  5 200.200.17.18 108 msec
But there's no translation entry.

Comment: It may not be supported on your router, it needs to be outside as that is the direction the traffic comes from to initiate the nat, the alernative would be inside source with static pat, but that wouldn’t give you load balancing

Comment: alternatively, you may be able to configure a static NAT on R1 to a dummy address on 192.168.32.16/28 and then configure your load-balancing NAT on SW3 with the inside/outside interfaces reversed, or look into SLB on SW3 if supported: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/slb/configuration/guide/slb_cg_book/slb_cg_xmp.html

Comment: You could also try using NAT NVI, remove the ip nat outside and inside statements and use ip nat enable on the interfaces instead, now remove the ip nat inside destination command and replace with: ip nat destination list RETAIL-WEB-GLOBAL pool RETAIL-WEB-LOCAL, remove your overload nat and replace with: ip nat source list NAT-GRP interface e0/0 overload

Comment: My IOS doesn't support ip nat destination list. So I went ahead with your another suggestion of SLB. Thank you.